# clearing ongoing notification in android

Tags: android

In my application iam showing a ongoing notification while doing a video upload. I want to clear the notification after upload. I searched a lot and cant get a clear answer.Please help me if anybody knows...

Answer (score 5):

From [Managing your Notifications](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html#ManageYourNotifications) in android documentation:

> You can also clear it manually with cancel(int), passing it the
>   notification ID, or clear all your notifications with cancelAll().

So you should perform following to hide the notification:

```
mNotificationManager.cancel(notification_id);
```

where `mNotificationManager` is `NotificationManager` object and `notification_id` is `int` identifier of notification passed to `NotificationManager` object:

```
mNotificationManager.notify(notification_id, notification);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just to show how this is done with Notification.Builder you can set the FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL like this:

```
Notification.Builder mBuilder = new Notification.Builder(getContext())
                    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.icon)
                    .setContentTitle("My notification")
                    .setContentText("Hello Notify!")
                    .setOngoing(true)
                    .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 1):

**You can clear your notification by clicking on it..!!**

Notification notification = new Notification("Your needed data..");

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;